# Magento - why setOriginalCustomPrice rounds price to 2 decimals?

Tags: magento, rounding

i want to insert quotation into cart and i am using function setOriginalCustomPrice

```
$specialprice = '0.49716'; 
 $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($specialPrice);
```

in cart it is inserted with price 0.50

any idea how to set Unit Price to 0.49716 in cart ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. In database prices are stored with 4 decimals only
2. By default currency precision is set to 2 decimals, and almost all operations using this option. You can try to change this option to 4 and maybe this helps.

You can use free extension [Currency Manager](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/et-currency-manager.html) to manage currency options.

Comment: i have already installed this extension and set precision to 6, but it still rounds price on 2 decimals